# Dmesg Unknown Flag

Tags: raspbian, operating-systems

When I execute `dmesg`, I get several messages containing unknown flag:

```
[416259.108023] pts0: unknown flag 7
[416259.108053] pts0: unknown flag 9 
[416327.464610] pts0: unknown flag 82 
[416432.916151] pts0: unknown flag 192 
[416432.916177] pts0: unknown flag 220
[416432.916186] pts0: unknown flag 81
```

They don't affect the system stability but I'm curious to known what they mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pts means [Pseudo terminal slave](http://www.linuxinfor.com/english/man4/pts.html). pts0 is actually `/dev/pts/0`. This is used for command line terminals and such. The output of the following command will tell you if there's something wrong with the permissions of this file:

```
ls -al /dev/pts/0
```

Likely you're running something via `su` and there are problems with the permissions of ownership of the file.